# Iterate over rows in Pandas DataFrame and generate new columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame with one column called `cardinality` that has in each row a list of *n* numbers. I would like to iterate over each row, take the first element from the list, and put it into a new column so that I have *n* columns.

Input:

```
input_data = pd.DataFrame({'cardinality':[[0,1,0,0,0],[1,0,1,0,0],[0,0,1,3,0],[0,0,0,1,1]]})
```

Desired output:

```
c_0  c_1  c_2  c_3  c_4
0    1    0    0    0
1    0    1    0    0
0    0    1    3    0
0    0    0    1    1
```

Here is my code:

```
iterator = 0
for row in input_data.itertuples():
    for cardinality in input_data['cardinality']:
        col_name = 'c_' + str(iterator)
        input_data[col_name] = [item[0] for item in input_data['cardinality']]
        input_data['cardinality'] = input_data['cardinality'].apply(lambda x: x.pop(0))
        iterator += 1
```

It seems like the `.pop` method is not the right way to remove the first item from the list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `tolist` on the series and create a new dataframe, then `add_prefx` to name it as expected.

```
output = pd.DataFrame(input_data['cardinality'].tolist()).add_prefix('c_')
print(output)
   c_0  c_1  c_2  c_3  c_4
0    0    1    0    0    0
1    1    0    1    0    0
2    0    0    1    3    0
3    0    0    0    1    1
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `pd.DataFrame` constructor and `rename`:

```
>>> pd.DataFrame(input_data['cardinality'].tolist()).rename(columns='c_{}'.format)
   c_0  c_1  c_2  c_3  c_4
0    0    1    0    0    0
1    1    0    1    0    0
2    0    0    1    3    0
3    0    0    0    1    1
```